# writeToFile with URL - URL doesnt exist next session

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using writeToFile to write an audio file to the local iphone directory. Next time I launch the app, the path / URL doesnt exist anymore and I cant retrieve my file.

Would appreciate any help.

Saving:

```
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir; 
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempFileName = [[NSString alloc] init];
    tempFileName = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.wav", tempFileName]];
    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:soundFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Reading:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
```

Where urlArray contains the path to the file and this If statement is false.

Comment: How do you make the URL?

Comment: have you checked that your file have been write in your directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't u save filePath in NSMutableArray and that in NSUserDefault

```
 //After writing file in doc dir
 if(success)
 {
   // Store the data
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   if(![defaults objectForKey:@"filePaths"]) //creating mutable array for first time
   {
      NSMutableArray *arrFilePaths = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      [defaults setObject:arrFilePaths forKey:@"filePaths"];
   }
   else //saving new soundFilePath in mutable array
   {
      NSMutableArray *arrFilePaths = [defaults objectForKey:@"filePaths"];
      [arrFilePaths addObject:soundFilePath];
      [defaults setObject:arrFilePaths forKey:@"filePaths"];
      [defaults synchronize];
   }

 }
```

Now u can read like this:

```
if([[defaults objectForKey:@"filePaths"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
{
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[defaults objectForKey:@"filePaths"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
  {
     //here is your file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you launch the app you need to search path again in NSDocument Directory as you do above.

You can make instance variable for filePath in AppDelegate class didFinishLaunching to record the path.

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempFileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"PutYourFileName"];
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.wav", tempFileName]];
```